# Connecting with newly created database (Oracle SQL Developer, DBCA)

Tags: database, oracle

Welcome all,
I have to ask some more advanced users about few things, that are connected with Oracle Databases. At first, I've created my own database by using Database Configuration Assistant. Okey, it was simple :)
The thing is, how to connect to my newly created database by sql developer for example. What data I should put into Database Connection form (hostname, port, sid etc.)? I will appreciate every kind of examples or where to look for informations. Of course, I've tried with ports, sid i created before, but it had no effect.

Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It's funny how you help people :( by giving them minus points.
Fortunatelly I've contend with problem by myself (the problem was connected with listener, dynamic service registration).
Thanks anyway.